# TYPO3 Add HTML5 data attribute to the tt_content.stdWrap.outerWrap

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I have extended tt_content table by new field "tx_myext_content_link", which is shown only for CType text and textpic. In database it's stored like page uid to which you should be redirected. The idea is that if tx_myext_content_link is setted in content record via backend, then on frontend I should have next html code

`<div id="c1">
   <div class="content-link" data-content-link="[path_to_the_content_link]">
     HERE IS CONTENT
   </div>
 </div>`

I wrote some typoscript:

`tt_content {
    stdWrap.outerWrap {
      typolink {
        parameter.field = tx_myext_content_link
        returnLast      = url
        wrap            = <div class="content-link" data-content-link="|"><div>
      }
      if.isTrue.field = tx_myext_content_link
    }
}`

But result of it is just

`<div id="c1">
  "path_to_the_content_link"
  HERE IS CONTENT
 </div>`

Now I stop because don't have any ideas. Please give me an advice how to implement it.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which version of TYPO3 do you use?

Comment: Can you extend your question with your TCA configuration?

Comment: Have found a solution. For this task I've used stdWrap.postUserFunc at  tt_content.text object. @ArekvanSchaijk thank you, but not needed anymore.